# How can a javascript string with special chars(️‍,) be split into individual characters?

Tags: javascript

I'm working with a component that splits text into characters. My expectation when splitting was that I will get ️‍ and characters like it as a single character.

Lets say we have the following text: "Hello ️‍ world ". If I split the text with:

```
"Hello ️‍ world ".split('') 
// result: "H", "e", "l", "l", "o", " ", "\ud83d", "\udd75", "️", "‍", …  
"️‍".split('') 
// result: Array [ "\ud83d", "\udd75", "️", "‍" ]
```

How can I split the string in such a way that these type of symbols are treated as one entity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the spread operator instead of `.split()`:

```
[..."Hello ️‍ world "]
```

As far as I know, the reason `spread` works and `split` doesn't is that `String.split` is separating [zero-width joiners](https://unicode.org/reports/tr14/#ZWJ) and `spread` is not.

```
"️‍".split().length // 4
[..."️‍"].length    // 3
```

Comment: Another option: `Array.from(input)` works too. (Although honestly I have no idea why XD)

Comment: It'd be awesome if you could include some explanation why this behaves differently from `split()`.  (Not criticizing the answer as it stands; just genuinely curious)

Comment: This works. Not sure why... but yeah. Thanks! Will have to investigate a bit more what spread and Array.from do. In a way, the `split()` was a hacky way of doing it.